# Verify a proof of a theorem left to be proved in a book

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

This is one of the "it is easy to see that" propositions in my real analysis textbook. I just wanted to know whether my justification(proof) to the proposition is correct or not.
Important definition:

> If $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that for all $a\in \mathbb R$, there is $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, $a_n>a$,then we will say that $a_n\rightarrow \infty$

Proposition:

> If $(a_n)\rightarrow \infty$ and $(b_n)\rightarrow l$ where $l \in \mathbb R$, then $(a_n)+(b_n) \rightarrow \infty$.

Since $(b_n)$ converges,it must be bounded. Thus, it must have a lower bound $u$ such that $u \leq b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
Thus, for any arbitrary real $a \in \mathbb R$, $a-u \geq a-b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Since $a-u \in \mathbb R$, there must be $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, $a_n > a-u \geq a-b_n \Rightarrow a_n > a-b_n \Rightarrow a_n+b_n>a$. Thus, by definition of divergence to infinity,we get $a_n+b_n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: It looks correct at least for me

Comment: I agree with @sansae. Excellent work!

Comment: And I appreciate the fact that you stop and ponder over the "it is easy to see that" kind of propositions. +1